# Combine Shaders

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

How would you combine these two shaders?

```
Shader "Legacy Shaders/Diffuse" {
Properties {
    _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
}
SubShader {
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
    LOD 200

CGPROGRAM
#pragma surface surf Lambert

sampler2D _MainTex;
fixed4 _Color;

struct Input {
    float2 uv_MainTex;
};

void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
    fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
    o.Albedo = c.rgb;
    o.Alpha = c.a;
}
ENDCG
}

Fallback "Legacy Shaders/VertexLit"
}
```

and

```
Shader "Custom/Jelly" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader {
        Pass {
            Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            struct v2f {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                half2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            v2f vert(appdata_base v) {
                v2f o;
                v.vertex.x += sign(v.vertex.x) * sin(_Time.w)/50;
                v.vertex.y += sign(v.vertex.y) * cos(_Time.w)/50;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.texcoord;
                return o;
            }


            half4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR {
                half4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                return c;
            }

            ENDCG
        }
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

I'm trying to combine then into one, i've tried various things but not quite sure how to get the color, with lighting enabled into the jelly shader.

I seem to be having an issue when i take the float2 uv_MainTex into the struct v2f, it doesn't seem to like that. Is it already there and i'm just misreading it?

Any help would be appreciated?

Thanks

Comment: Besides one being the new unity standard shader they basically do the same thing in the fragment shader, except the second one doesnt multiply the color.  the first one you dont have the vertex shader defined, so it is using unity's standard vertex shader for that.

Comment: Adding in the color multiplication would be easy, too.